# JavaFX TreeView cellFactory styling bug

Tags: javafx, treeview, styling

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, if it's a bug / not supported. I'm trying to set the background color of a treeitem with the updateItem-Method. But when I'm scrolling around, other treeitems get colorized too.

Here's code to reproduce the problem:

```
public class Main extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(getTree());

        treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
            {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item != null)
                {
                    setText(item);

                    if (item.equals("c5"))
                    {
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: YELLOW");
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(treeView);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TreeItem<String> getTree()
    {
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("root");
        TreeItem<String> a = new TreeItem<String>("a");
        TreeItem<String> b = new TreeItem<String>("b");
        TreeItem<String> c = new TreeItem<String>("c");

        root.getChildren().add(a);
        root.getChildren().add(b);
        root.getChildren().add(c);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            c.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("c" + i));
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to undo the styling in case a `TreeCell` is emptied or the item is replaced with one that should not be styled yellow. Also you do not remove text, if the cell becomes empty or contains a `null` item:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        // clear background
        setStyle(null);
    } else {
        setText(item);
        if (item.equals("c5")) {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: YELLOW");
        } else {
            // clear background
            setStyle(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that the updateItem refers to the cell itself like a wrapper and you have to update it when the content changes. But it's still not clear to me (technically) why there are severall other cells that get colorized, instead of just one.

Comment: @Michael_S: When you scroll, items are assigned to different cells. This is done to limit the number of `Node`s used to show the content. (There is only one cell per visible "row" in the `TreeView`, but the number nodes with only expanded ancestors (= visible items) can be arbitrary large.)